# Chef (well, Test Kitchen) hanging when using local cookbook

Tags: chef, testing

I am new to Chef, trying to put together a POC for my company.
So I've got a project that has two cookbooks under the cookbook folder. One cookbook is a "base" cookbook called 'hydra-base', the other (called 'automator') is supposed to extend it. Right now all I have is a test in the extending cookbook, and a recipe invocation.

My problem is when I attempt to verify it with Kitchen, everything uploads ok until it gets to trying to apply the recipe, then I get the following line:
`Recipe:  hydra-base::default` and then kitchen just hangs. It has been idle for about 45 minutes now. If I break out of the tool (ctrl-c) then rerun kitchen converge, it gives me this error then hangs:

`[2018-01-09T17:35:23+00:00] WARN: Chef client 1514 is running, will wait for it to finish and then run.`

So it appears that chef still thinks its trying to update something. Here are the relevant files:

```
# automator/recipes/default.rb
include_recipe 'hydra-base::default'

# automator/Berksfile
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'hydra-base', path: '../hydra-base'
metadata

# automator/metadata.rb
depends 'hydra-base'
```

calling `kitchen verify -l debug` does not seem to provide any additional information after the line that hangs.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to fix this or how to get more information out of kitchen?
Thanks

Comment: We can't have any clue of what chef is doing in your hydra-base cookbook without seing the recipe... You can pass a log option to chef within kitchen but without your kitchen.yaml it's impossible to answer properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that AWS was just excruciatingly slow and apt-get (applied in the base) was timing out. I would have known this had I gone back earlier and tried testing the base cookbook.